# move location of table of contents in quarto docx output?

Tags: r, ms-word, quarto

I am working on a report for a customer that requires a title page, currently formatted as a `{quarto}` Book. By default, `{quarto}` places the table of contents at the front of the document. Is there a mechanism to either:

1. move the table of contents further down in the document by modifying the `_quarto.yml` file
2. concatenate DOCX files, the first of which is a one-page file with the title page, and the second of which is the rendered `{quarto}` book

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have been (rightfully) reminded that I let this post go derelict without providing follow-up with solution we landed on.

TR;DL up-front. Define your title page and other front matter in a `before-body.tex` in your project and reference it in your `_quarto.yml`

Slightly longer explanation. Define your front matter in `before-body.tex`. Ours had some sponsor logos in it, so looked something like:

```
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\includegraphics{images/logos.png}

\vspace{1.5in}
\begin{LARGE}
\textbf{Title of Volume}
\end{LARGE}

\begin{large}
Contract Information
\end{large}

\vspace{2.5in}
A. Author, B. Author, & Z. Author

\today


\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

Then, reference it in your `_quarto.yml`:

```
pdf:
   template-partials:
      - before-body.tex
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been open for a while, so I'm guessing you found a solution. I'm not sure if this will work for exactly your purpose, but since no one has suggested an answer, I post what I found for a similar situation.

I just created a title page and toc in docx output using the reference-doc by editing the Heading 1 and TOC Heading styles (from modify in the styles pane) format -> paragraph -> line and page breaks -> check page break before.

This will put everything with TOC Heading and Heading 1 style (likely your first thing after the TOC) on a new page. Effectively creating separate Title and TOC pages.

Hopefully this helps someone!

Comment: Thank you for reminder, will write a quick post on our implementation to solve... involved a bit of LaTeX and some `_quarto.yml`-fu